# Word Active Document Get Height of Selection area

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office365, office-addins

i want to get height of selected text area in word document in c#

Please see in image selected area which is shows in light gray color.

any one know how to get it.

[image]

Comment: That selection is a combination of the line spacing and spaces before and after in the paragraph settings. Unless the line spacing is set to Exact, the line spacing height will vary depending on the font choice. AFAIK, this can only be determined by measuring samples.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply, As you said that selection is a combination of the line spacing and spaces and also depends on the font, so is there any way in to get this through programming(c#)?.

Comment: I'm more familiar with VBA, where you can use ```Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)``` on successive lines to get the line height indirectly.

Comment: Thanks for the information John, i will try to implement your suggestion in c#, might be this help me and resolve my problem.